# How to get the index of matching group in the regex crate?

Tags: regex, rust

I only find one way is that using a Captures iter to check which index is Some(..).

```rust
let re = Regex::new(r"([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9]*)|([0-9]+)|(\.)|(=)").unwrap();

for cap in re.captures_iter("asdf.aeg = 34") {
    let mut index = 0;
    for (i, name) in cap.iter().enumerate() {
        if i == 0 {continue}
        if let Some(_) = name {index = i; break;}
    }
    println!("group {:?}, match {:?}", index, cap.at(index).unwrap());
}
```

Is there a proper way?

Answer (score 3):

I think your code is almost as close as you can get. Here is a slightly more idiomatic version:

```
let re = Regex::new(r"([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9]*)|([0-9]+)|(\.)|(=)").unwrap();

for cap in re.captures_iter("asdf.aeg = 34") {
    let index = cap.iter().enumerate()
        .skip(1)                  // skip the first group
        .find(|t| t.1.is_some())  // find the first `Some`
        .map(|t| t.0)             // extract the index
        .unwrap_or(0);            // get the index
    println!("group {:?}, match {:?}", index, cap.at(index).unwrap());
}
```

Comment: But the "find the first `Some`" step still takes O(n) time to get the index at the worst case. Is there a way to just get the index in O(1) time? Why didn't the regex remember the index when matching the group and then return to user?

Comment: I don't know the reason why regex API does not have such feature. My guess is, unless your regex contains thousands of groups, I don't think it really matters. You can always submit a feature request to the regex [issue tracker](https://github.com/rust-lang/regex/issues).

Comment: Yes, please submit an issue. Please also explain the *problem you're trying to solve*. (Which I don't see described anywhere in this question.)

Comment: (Note that I have fixed the code to handle the situation when no group has matched except the whole regex (could happen if the matched alternative does not have a group))